# Add sort and search to html table where a set of rows is returned instead of columns

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, arrays

On a modx site using migxdb & bloX to show results from a form on the front end I have the following challenge to overcome.
I can display the data very nicely, my issue is when I get a large number of form data it is too long to expect people to scroll. 
I need to add search & filter.
I cannot input a traditional search & filter code because it just searches for specific data under columns. 
Most codes search columns whereas I need a data set of submitted rows tied to an id shown upon search.
My front end form generates a list of rows each time the form is submitted, each one is data set, every time the form is submitted it generates another data set.
I need to input a search where all data is displayed from each submitted data set, for example a search for a town should reveal all rows in any data set where this town name appears.
I only want to enter one filter which will be date related, again the whole data set should be shown ascending/descending according to its date field.

This is the html code I need to add the search/filter to:

```
<div>
<style>
table, th, td
{
border-collapse:collapse;
border:1px solid black;
}
th, td
{
padding:5px;
}
th, td
{
text-align:left;
}
</style>
<table>
<tr>
<th colspan="2"><h3>Transport Job: [[+id]]<br></h3></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Job Description</td>
<td>[[+freightcaptitle]]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Vehicle Type</td>
<td>[[+vehicletype]]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Departure Town</td>
<td>[[+deptown]]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Arrival Town</td>
<td>[[+arrtown]]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Cubic Metres Available</td>
<td>[[+cubmt]]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Date</td>
<td>[[+freightdate]]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Detailed Information</td>
<td>[[+freightvehicledetail]]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Contact Details</td>
<td>[[+freightvehiclecontact]]</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Any code examples to achieve what I'm trying to do would be appreciated :-)

Answer (score 1):

You should look into using and established plugin, like [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/)

Comment: I tried listjs but this just returned results within each data set, I need it to return results from all relevant data sets.

Comment: are you creating a new table for each data set or appending the results to the existing table? It sounds like you might be looking for a server-side search, depending on your data.

Comment: I also looked at data tables, but (unless I miss something) this just concentrates on returning data from columns as opposed to a collective data set of rows which is what I need.

Comment: do you mean to say rows instead of columns? DataTables filter brings back any rows that are matched.

Comment: Yes but, i do not want it to return a specific row, I need it to return a set of rows within a data set. If the 'search' term appears in one row then the search must return every row from that data set.

Comment: Every time the form is submitted it sends the data to the mysql db. This is saved as normal in columns. I am turning these columns into rows on the front end because of space limitation. So each set of data is separated on the front end.

Comment: you could use [DataTables custom filtering](http://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html), but it sounds like a better solution would be to make the search happen server-side and adjust what you return based on the search.